# Bootkube API server unable to start

Tags: kubernetes, coreos, coreos-ignition

I am following the CoreOS tutorial for [self-hosted Kubernetes](https://coreos.com/matchbox/docs/latest/bootkube.html) and I am having some issues with the Bootkube API server. Using the Bootkube example from the [recommended repository](https://github.com/coreos/matchbox) I have only changed the `ssh_authorized_keys` metadata field in nodes 1,2 and 3. All other settings are the same as in the repository. However, after running `bootkube-start` via `systemctl` on `node1` I check the logs using `ssh core@node1.example.com 'journalctl -f -u bootkube'` and I am getting `Unable to determine api-server readiness: Get https://node1.example.com:443/version: dial tcp 172.17.0.21:443: getsockopt: connection refused`. Does anyone know of the best ways to debug such an issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the api-server is having issues while starting, or that you have some networking/firewall/dns problem.

You should be able to `ssh core@node1.example.com` and then get the full bootkube logs there via `sudo journalctl -u bootkube`.